# How convert dtype object column so the results appear correctly in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am facing a problem when saving/reading a csv file. I save a dataframe into csv. Among many columns it has a column named id

```
ID
0000
0011
0022
A979
```

The problem is when I am saving into a csv using the following command

```
df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

the results appear as follows

```
ID
0
11
22
A979
```

It basically erases the 0 in the front.

I believe excel believes the data is int and that is why they are erased. I tried changing the format of the column in excel to string and still it does not work. I noticed that the dtype of that column is object. Thus I tried the following

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str)
```

and the dtype remained object. I also tried

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype('string')
```

that did not work as well.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].astype('|S')
```

I noticed the results were printed as follows

```
ID
b'0000'
b'0011'
b'0022'
A979
```

Then I tried to use

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('b', '')
```

but I get the following error

```
Cnnot use .str.replace with values of inferred dtype 'bytes'
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

EDIT1: When saved with excel the output is correct. It seems to be an issue with csv only

Comment: Can you test in some another edited like `Nontepad++` output? Because excel can removed `0` I guess

Comment: you have hexadecimal number in that columns. can you check the column dtype please?

Comment: Hello. The issue is that it needs to be read by an excel so I cannot avoid that. The dtype of the column is object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by opening the data frame using the dtype option within the pd.read_csv.

In your case:

```
df.to_csv(path, index=False, dtype= {"ID": object})
```

Hope it helps!